# Does Keras' ImageDataGenerator randomly apply transformations to every image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN using the Keras ImageDataGenerator class. My code looks something like:

```
from keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

    data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range = 15,
        width_shift_range = 0.1,
        height_shift_range = 0.1,
        horizontal_flip = True
    )
    data_generator.fit(xtrain)

    es = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', mode = 'min', verbose = 1, patience = 100)
    history = CNN_model.fit(data_generator.flow(xtrain, ytrain, batch_size = batch_size), \
                                                                          epochs = num_epochs, \
                                                                          validation_data = (xval, yval), \
                                                                          callbacks = [LearningRateScheduler(learning_rate_schedule), es])
```

Now I have looked at the documentation and I don't entirely understand if it does this image augmentation to every image in each batch, or it is randomly selects a percentage of them? I am assuming that it does augmentation to each image but I am trying to understand.

If it is doing this to every image in my dataset, this means that I am not at all using an un-augmented image for any of my training epochs, correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I did the test and it's applied randomly *per image*, even though these pictures come from the same batch.

Based on my reading of the documentation, I have no reason to think that only some of the images are transformed and that others are left intact.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from skimage.data import chelsea
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

imgs = np.stack([chelsea() for i in range(4*4)], axis=0)

data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range = 90,
    width_shift_range = 0.1,
    height_shift_range = 0.1,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    preprocessing_function=lambda x: x[..., np.random.permutation([0, 1, 2])]
)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=.2, hspace=.2)
for index, image in enumerate(next(data_gen.flow(imgs)).astype(int)):
    ax = plt.subplot(4, 4, index + 1)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is really good. Thank you for the code. So I am assuming one operation is chosen per image, or is it possible to have multiple operations be applied together? The documentation isnt clear on the random semantics.

Comment: All transformations are independently random. Look at the new example.

Comment: Aye. I think I see it now. So I believe my question is answered. the degree of randomness is applied within the ranges that are supplied (or binary flip for the parameters that use a boolean) but it is now confirmed that each of the operations ARE applied, the degree of which is the random component.